# Configuring Ubuntu/adding udev rule

Tags: udev, arduino

I'm working on 16.04 and trying to setup the Arduino IDE for use with a Genuino 101.I have the ide installed, v 1.8.2, in my home folder. It compiles sketches and picks up the board serial number as well as other details correctly. According to the Arduino site, one needs to execute

```
sudo ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
```

inside a shell to gain upload permissions.

When I execute this through the terminal I get the error message

```
sudo: /home/16737547/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule: command not found
```

Is this command looking for v 1.6.4 of the IDE? I have tried to modify the command to

```
sudo ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.8.2+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
```

but it did not resolve the error message. Upon entering the folder from the terminal using

```
cd ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load
```

and using ls

I find the only folder listed is 2.0.1.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem on this forum: <http://www.arduino.cn/thread-45886-1-1.html> Even though the user is using Arch.

Answer (score 1):

I found the rule file in the following location:

```
~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/arc32/2.0.2/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
```

and ran following commands to resolve the issue:

```
chmod u+x ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/arc32/2.0.2/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule && 
sudo ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/arc32/2.0.2/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
```